# Connecting android application to MySQL through SQL server express

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server

I've been looking for a way to connect an Android application to a MySQL server. Tried different codes and asked many programmers. Didn't get anywhere.
I'd be happy if anyone would be able to guide me on what codes I need to look for or what it is that's missing in the code I tried.

The application I got to make involves creating some sql tables. For instance, at the beggining it needs to veriffy login data given by a user against that data in one of those tables.

In addition to Android studio, I was guided to install and use SQL server express (nothing else).

I created a table through SQL server express 2008 R2, but the connection to the server didn't work. The codes I found always involved a password and a username for the connection. Is that mandatory? I didn't get a username for the connection when I installed the server. It involved getting an instance name and a password.

I found a code in which one can define a password and a usename:

```
    private Connection conn;

    public MySQLConnection() throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("At MySQLConnection()");

        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user","fred");
            props.setProperty("password","secret");
            props.setProperty("ssl","true");

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://zivpc/workers?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("connected");


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Trying to connect results in the following exception:
`CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Tried finding what are the correct connection parameters are, but could find the ones that work.

Comment: `MySQL server express 2008` ? What is that ?

Comment: MySQL server express 2008 R2.

Comment: the point @Cid is making is that there's MySQL, and there's SQL Server Express. They're two completely separate products, from two completely separate companies.

Comment: It was a mistake. It's sql server express 2008 R2. Not Mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

If your database resides in a server, you could consider making a http wrapper which can talk to the database. The Http end point can be a bridge between your database and an external application(Your Android app in this case).

The Android App can hit these http end points for login or whatever use case you might want to have.

Comment: By using Apache, for example?

Comment: @D.Joe yes, that's one option. The important part is that your Android app shouldn't be directly accessing the database on your server because that would mean that the server is exposed to the internet. You need an API on a public website, and that API is the only thing that can talk to the database server. That API doesn't just pass through any random SQL statement but rather has a fixed set of things the client can do, which are then performed via one or more SQL statements executed from the web server.

Comment: Any web server and any programming language would suffice. Ex. You could use go lang on a Linux server . The go lang API would be the interface between your app and the database. This way the app would just be hitting a simple http end point

Comment: Should I use an http wrapper if the database is on my computer?

Comment: You should ideally host your dB on the cloud. You can still have your dB in your computer and have a http wrapper around it , provided your IP address is static. This way you can access the http end point via a URL.